# Should we explicitly kill a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

i create three threads in my main program. i have for loop in each thread. After executing the statements in the run() method , each thread automatically gets destroyed or killed by itself. correct? Is my understanding correct ?

IS there any Java standard reference where it mentions that there is no need to explicitly kill a thread and it does by itself. i have been trying to read and browse many articles. but still not getting 100% confidence.

I would highly appreciate if any expert over here could reply and help me out. Thanks in advance!!!

```
public class Demo {
    TestA A = new TestA("TestA",threadAList);
    TestA B = new TestB("TestB",threadBList);
    TestA C = new TestC("TestC",threadCList);
}

class TestA implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    public TestA(String name,List threadAList) {
        System.out.println(name);
        this.threadAList = threadAList;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("TestA Thread started");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(log);
            doing some action to move the faild file to a failure folder    
        }
        finally {
            log.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the thread is automatically destroyed and made available for garbage collection once its `Runnable`'s `run` method has returned.

Comment: "the thread is automatically [...] garbage collected": not true. The `Thread` instance (as any instance of any class) cannot be garbage collected while it is strongly reachable, even if the `run` method (and the corresponding thread) finishes.

Comment: As long as you don't keep your own reference to it, the thread should be available. And obviously it is only made available for GC and not forcibly destroyed just like any regular object.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. So how  do we explicitly kill a thread, when it normally exits from the thread. if the thread is still in the memory and not garbage collected, will it result in any out of memory issues?

Comment: i am having a main program in which i create 3 threads. the 3 respective threads will in turn call some other java class. at the end of the run() method execution, i want the thread to be destroyed or killed or stopped so that the thread does not keep hanging around and does not occupy the memory and result in any out of memory issues. Hope i am clear. I would appreciate if you can please share your thoughts.

Comment: If your `run` method terminates, the thread will terminate and its memory cleared if you don't hold any references to it. To explicitly kill a running thread, it's best to set a shared flag that `run` checks regularly. This only works if you have some sort of looping structure. It would help if you could describe what those three threads are doing.

Comment: hi David, I have mentioned the code snippet as part of my initial question. Please take a look at it. i have 3 threads, thread A, B and c instantiated from my main program. when i exit the thread, will the thread A be memory cleared or should i nullify the instance something like this (this.t = null; in finally block). am not too sure.... What would you recommend. the above is the structure of my current program. Looking forward for your response.

Comment: Also, Please let me know if the above exception handling is fine. as i need to have failure details , it would be useful if i take the exception messages to a log file. thanks!

Comment: Each `TestA` and thread pair reference each other which the garbage collector will detect. The use of threads here doesn't change the normal GC rules. There's no reason to set `t` to `null` before letting `run` terminate.

Comment: Thanks. So, the GC will automatically detect when the run method terminates. and at the end of each thread execution, the respctive thread instance is made available for garbage collection and we need not do anything explicitly when we exit from the run() method. is my understanding correct? please let me know.

Comment: Correct, threads work just like all other objects in Java. When they are not reachable via hard references, they are available for the GC.

Comment: Thanks David for confirming my understanding. good news is we need not program anything specific for threads to be destroyed and will not occupy the memory after it completes execution.

Comment: @user1257836 - Please accept the answer if you're satisfied that is addresses your question.

Comment: Should i click any accept button here. i am not able to see any. pls clarify

Comment: Click the check mark under the answer that most addresses your question if you feel it answers it correctly. Kinda hard with no answers getting any upvotes. :)

Comment: you have mentioned hard references. will the threads not be reachable via hard references?

Comment: If you keep a hard reference yourself, yes, this will block GC just is it will with *every other type of object*. Otherwise, the JVM has no reason to keep a hard reference once the thread's `run` method has terminated so it should be available for GC.

Comment: Hi David, is there any way to confirm if the thread is killed at the end of execution? by knowing this, we will be sure that there wont be any out of memory exceptions. thanks in advance!

Comment: Trust the JVM? You should really be starting new questions, but look up [soft references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html).

Answer (score 0):

threads expire automatically when they finish execution. it is however ususally good practice to provide a point in your code (i.e. at shutdown) where you ensure that threads have finished (or wait for them to finsih) this will also let you determain if any of the threads has become stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. How would you recommend to provide in the code when it exits the run() method. Currently, i have only System.out.println that am exiting the thread.

Comment: 'this will also let you determain if any of the threads has become stuck in an infinite loop' - what if the thread was designed as an infinite loop?  It is usually good practice to start such threads, (in fact, all threads that have no overriding need for shutdown notification), as daemons so that they do not delay the app close.

Comment: Hi,Thanks again! Sorry to mention, I am still not clear. Should effective exception handling help these kind of scenarios ? Can you please give me some samples. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When your thread exits the run() method it dies and will be garbage collected.  There is no need to explicitly kill it.  In fact you should never "kill" or "stop" threads.  Threads must exit gracefully through finishing the run method or dying because an uncaught exception was thrown.  Make sure you understand what conditions an InterruptedException can be thrown and understand how to properly respond to it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

```
public void run() {
   try {
      while( !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() ) {
         try {
            // do some long running work here
         } catch( ExceptionThatDoesntStopTheThread ex ) {
            logger.warn( "Hey I got an exception, but I'm not going anywhere", ex );
         }
      }
      // if you are forced to catch InterruptedException (wait(), sleep(), etc) 
      // put it outside the loop as it signifies someone has asked this thread to 
      // shutdown.
   } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
      logger.info("Interrupted exception received shutting down.");
   } finally {
      // clean up anything you need to handle, and log a statement
      logger.info("Thread done.");
   }
}
```

If a client wants to request a thread to shutdown it just needs to call interrupt() on the thread instance:

```
Thread someThread = new Thread( new MyRunnable() );
...
someThread.interrupt();
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the quick responses.

Comment: Now i understand that there is nothing to be done from the programmer end to kill or stop the thread once it has performed its actions. it gets killed automatically and the JVM takes care of it.

Comment: For any unexpected conditions, i will handle the exceptions optimally.

Comment: i see lot of code samples with run() { while(true) { execute steps}} .  the "true", signifies the thread is active?? Can you please clarify if my understanding is correct . is this is an efficient way just to make sure the code is executed only when the thread is alive? thanks!

Comment: I prefer not using while(true).  Instead I like to simply check the interruption mechanism provided by Java, and it's just like having your own boolean to signal a shutdown.  Point is this is provided for you already so no reason to do it over again.  I've put a template in my answer along with where different places where exception handling should belong.

Comment: Thank you so much for the template and the explanation.My understanding based on the template above - 1. as long as the the thread is not interrupted, we can go ahead and execute the run method. this is illustrated by  !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(). here, currentthread() is required as we are checking this particular thread is interrupted.Please let me know if my understanding is correct. thanks again!

Comment: ExceptionThatDoesntStopTheThread - you have mentioned above is the generic "Exception" which will handle all the exceptions which occurs due to the code in the run(). is that correct?

Comment: the try/catch should be sufficient enough or should we go for UncaughtexceptionHandlers? thanks again for all the clarifications!

Comment: try/catch using either Exception or Throwable will be enough to trap all exceptions that could be thrown out of your code.  UncaughtExceptionHandlers is mainly for code that lives inside frameworks like Swing, J2EE, etc.  Since you own the very last stackframe (ie run()) you can trap everything.

Comment: Hi Chubbard, Thanks for the details. But if the main thread should be informed about the exceptions in the child thread, should we go for Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandlers?

Comment: Exceptions don't travel across threads.  So the main thread will NOT be informed about exceptions.  If the main thread needs to know about the status of a result or computation then you have to handle that yourself even with UncaughtExceptionHandlers.  There are clever and cleaner ways to do this using Future.get() where Future.get() will rethrow an exception on the main thread if the child received an exception, but at the end of the day what is the main thread really going to do when an exception occurs?  Probably just log some junk and tell the user.Which thread does that matters much less.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i am using the simple try catch() strategy and catching the exceptions in the respective threads itself. hoping that it works out!

Answer (score 0):

Well behaved threads are not killed, they die on their own accord. How they die, or how they are signaled to die are not part of Java per se, but an artifact of the application.

Killing of threads in Java is frowned upon because of the severity of process. Much like an OutOfMemory exception, many classes are simply not designed to have the rug yanked out from underneath them. Many check for explicitly checked exceptions, or for other "expected" events within their own code, that they themselves control, but few handled the truly out of the blue events that can happen in the JVM (such as OOM and thread death). For example, if a class it performing a static initializer "that only happens once", and that initializer is interrupted, that class is "ruined forever".

This is why killing a thread is supported, but not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instructional example to demonstrate a thread is removed from existence without overt action.

```
The output looks like:
    I'm dying.
    I've been burried.

class Test {
static boolean flag = true;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    class T extends Thread {
        public T(Runnable r) {
            super(r);
        }
        protected void finalize() {
            System.out.println("I've been burried.");
            flag=false;
        }
    }
    T t = new T(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("I'm dying.");
        }});
    t.start();
    t=null;
    while(flag) {System.gc(); Thread.sleep(13);};
}    
}
```